# Python Regex return both results when 2 conditions set which partially satisfy one another WITHOUT IF statements nor Test groups and NOT AS A TUPLE

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples, findall

I'm going to have quite a few questions about regex in the coming days. Out of 10 challenges I gave myself over the past 5 days, I managed to solve 6.

I'm hoping the following isn't simple and embarrassing, but what I'm trying to do use re.findall to return results for both conditions even though the condition for set 2 may have already partially been satisfied by set 1.

Example (Problem):

```
>>> str = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
>>> re.findall('ab1cd|ab', str)
['ab1cd']
>>> re.findall('ab|ab1cd', str)
['ab']
```

So notice that depending on whichever comes first in the OR statement determines what the single element of the array is. What I want is to be able to return both for a 2 element array and preferably not a Tuple. The readings I've done on regex ANDing have focused on making regexes match 2 different strings as opposed to returning multiple results that may mutually satisfy one another partially. Below is what I desire.

Desired Output:

```
>>> str = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
>>> re.findall('{SOMETHING_THAT_RETURNS_BOTH}', str)
['ab', 'ab1cd']
```

The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
>>> re.findall('ab|[\S]+?(?=2e)', str)
['ab', '1cd']
>>> re.findall('ab|[\S]+(?=2e)', str)
['ab', '1cd']
```

but the second capture group ignores ab. Is there a directive in regex to say restart from the beginning? (?:^) seems to work the same as a ^ and using it in several ways didn't help thus far. Please note I DO NOT want to use regex IF statements nor test to see if a previous group matched just yet because I'm not quite ready to learn those methods before forming a more solid foundation for the things I don't yet know.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `re.findall`, *independent of the regex used*, is documented as returning *non-overlapping* strings. I think you are trying to do to much with regexes alone; they don't let you perform flow control.

Comment: Wow. Did not realize that that was what the documentation was refrring to. Thanks so much for the quick help. Duly noted

Answer (score 1):

If you can relax tuple requirement then following regex with 2 independent lookaheads is needed due to your requirement of capturing overlapping text:

```
>>> print re.search(r'(?=(ab1cd))(?=(ab))', str).groups()
('ab1cd', 'ab')
```

Both lookaheads have a capturing group thus giving us required output.

You can also use `findall`:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(?=(ab1cd))(?=(ab))', str)[0]
('ab1cd', 'ab')
```

Comment: This is great and is definitely useful! It actually helped me learn what i was progressing toward which is specifying capture groups inside of a lookahead. Hopefully I can find a way to eliminate the tuple. I will play around with yours to see what I can get. I actually came up with something really similar while experimenting, but yours is far better than mine. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the desired output the regex pattern shouldn't really require any lookaheads:

```
str = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k1cd'
res = re.findall(r'((ab)?1cd)', str)
[list(row) for row in res][0]
```

> The `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times
>   as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

**Result**:

```
['ab1cd', 'ab']
```

Comment: That's a really cool solution! I love the help, definitely; through this question, I'm learning the answers to a few questions I'd planned to ask in the future. In the case of your solution, I actually wanted the findall to save the result to a list without any extra steps. Still, I remove the no greedy declaration from yours and reshaped your process using these:  Option1 ___ list(re.findall('((ab)1cd)', s)[0])   --------       Option2[step1] ____  res = re.findall('((ab)1cd)', s)  
 ----- Option2[step2] _____ list(res[0])

Comment: *Grammar correction. *Through your help I removed the non- greedy declaration from yours...
Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sorry. I can only edit for 5 minutes. Needed to mention, in the comment above s => str. It should have been Option1 ___ list(re.findall('((ab)1cd)', str)[0]) -------- Option2[step1] ____ res = re.findall('((ab)1cd)', str) ----- Option2[step2] _____ list(res[0])